# search functionality for json content

Tags: android, json, search

I developed one android app where all the content is fetched from json which is done using asynctask and populated in listviews. I have almost 10 custom list views in the app. Now I want to implement a single search in the home page. I am new to android. Please suggest me, how to implement it. Search is needed for only titles node in the json object. I knew how to set up search widget, listview xml, adding manifest file metadata, and search activity to main activity. I want to know, how to implement single search for all custom list views.

My json file looks like below. Custom listview contains image and title and description.

```
   [
     {
         "name":"Steve",
         "title":"How things work",
         "image":url,
     },
     {
         "name":"Jack",
         "date":"helium extraction",
         "image":url,
     }
   ]
```

Comment: Does the activity has different fragment for different custom view?

Comment: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

Comment: ten categories in the home page as buttons, i used intents to open the specified activities. Fragment is used only for the home page with navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** First , create an Object `User` for example:

```
public class User{
  String name;
  String title;
  String UrlImage;

  // setter
  // getter

}
```

**2.** Then create a `ListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter`  to populate data in ListView

**(look at this tutoruel from [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/))**

**Also see [this tutoriel](http://www.tutozone.info/2014/10/tutoriel-listview-personnalisee-avec.html) (in French) from [TutoZone.info](http://www.tutozone.info/) to see how populate data in custiom adapter**

**3.** For search fonctionality ,create a layout layout_search that contains an `EditText` *searchEditText*

**4.** Include this layout on each layout that contains a listView with your data (from Json)

**5.** In Your asynckTask, add each `JsonObject` to A `ArrayList<User>` , at the end of parsing you will have a arrayList that contains all of data `[User(name, title,url)]` and populated in your listView

**6.** BVack to the search fonctionality  , on each activity add a listener to the editText: addTextChangedListener:

```
EditText fillSearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);

fillSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = fillSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

              ArrayList<User> list =  search(text); // our function 
            }
        });
```

**7.**  Add search method that return a list contains all data ythat we search (starts with the text entered by user in EditText) :

```
 public  ArrayList<User>search(String s)
{
     ArrayList<User> list= new ArrayList<User>();

         for (User u: listeUsers) {  // listUsers= contains all data parsed in asynckTask
             if(User.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(s))
             {
                 list.add(u);
             }
           }
         return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. will it work if I change the content in the server side in the future. I mean json...

Comment: I don't want to show search edit field in all pages. but in point 4 you mentioned something like "4. Include this layout on each layout that contains a listView with your data (from Json)"

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing for fast searching, save required data in an arrayList thn just make a for loop run with ".contains"

```
JSONObject jsonObjRecv = HttpClientJSON.SendHttpPost(Appconstants.BASE_URL + Appconstants.DATA, jobjsend);
```

You will get json response in jsonObjRecv, after that use:

```
title = jsonObjRecv.getString("title");
```

now with

```
 if(title.contains(//your search string)){//conditions and code }
```